# Design View ListView ASP.NET Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to input logic in the source view in Asp.Net ListView. The problem is that the program is writing on the screen false or true when executing "If (isItTrue(test))". Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
   <%# test= Eval("testId")%>
          <%
              If (isItTrue(test)) Then

              %>
           <asp:Button ID="btnTest"  runat="server" Text="Like" />
           <%
           Else
               %>
               <asp:Label runat="server" Text="hello" </asp:Label>

           <%
           End If
               %>
```

Comment: can you show the code where you are acutally using a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) to check informations like this and show or hide the controls using your condition. try something like this in your code behine:

```
protected void ListViewTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // if it is data item
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        // call your function
        if (isItTrue("test"))
        {
            // show the button
            e.Item.FindControl("btnTest").Visible = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            // show the label
            e.Item.FindControl("lblTest").Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your Listview, you could do something like this, setting the event and adding the controls on the place holder

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewTest" DataSourceID="..." OnItemDataBound="ListViewTest_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
      </table>          
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr style="background-color: #CAEEFF" runat="server">
        <td>
           <%-- both controls are here --%>     
          <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Like"></asp:Button>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTest"  runat="server" Visible="false" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not this line:   `<%# test= Eval("testId")%>` that is writing true or false to the output?